# Swift: How to create milestones / challenges IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create some basic achievements for my app (such as using it for 30 days in a row, using it 10 mins a day etc.) but can't seem to find any documentation on how to go about this. I have looked at the Game Kit but that doesn't seem to really fit with what I need as my project is not multiplayer and I can't think of an easy to code in these challenges.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Managing State Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW5) section in the iOS documentation.

What you can do is store the dates when the app becomes Active and Inactive/Background. Based on this you could calculate if a user is *using it 10 mins a day*.

The same way store a date every day the app becomes Active, then have some logic which determines if some has been *using it for 30 days in a row*.

Comment: This looks promising. I will have a play around with it and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into ways of data persistence - NSUserDefaults, Core Data etc and do some calculations on the dates to see if the streak is maintained or not.

Comment: I am already using core data to store the streaks so if I can use this it would be handy! But how would I set the code up to check if the dates are in a streak of say 10 days in a row?

Comment: You could have a variable say 'counter' and then in your core data you could store the time when the app was opened. Now whenever the app is opened you could compare it with the time(last record) in your DB. If the difference is less than 24 hrs (depends on which format you are saving the time) then increment the counter by one. And then see if  value of counter is 10, >10, > 30 as you wish. Else if the difference is >24 hrs you clear all timestamps from your database(optional) and reset the counter to 0. counter variable too is stored in core data database.